# json dict to excel - python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data like this,

```
finalResult = [{'40': {'A': 3.1, 'B': 5.62, 'C': 5.99, 'D': 5.06, 'E': 5.09}}, 
{'50': {'A': 2.95, 'B': 5.21, 'C': 5.41, 'D': 4.64, 'E': 4.5}}, 
{'60': {'A': 2.35, 'B': 4.8, 'C': 4.83, 'D': 4.08, 'E': 3.62}},
{'70': {'A': 1.94, 'B': 4.6, 'C': 4.41, 'D': 3.65, 'E': 3.62}]
```

I want to export this data to excel with some format like below,

```
    40      50      60      70    
A   3.1     2.95    2.35    1.94    
B   5.62    5.21    4.8     4.6     
C   5.99    5.41    4.83    4.41    
D   5.06    4.64    4.08    3.65    
E   5.09    4.5     3.62    3.62
```

How to achieve this?

Finally the data should export to excel like below,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension with `DataFrame` contructor and [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in finalResult],axis=1)
print (df)
     40    50    60    70
A  3.10  2.95  2.35  1.94
B  5.62  5.21  4.80  4.60
C  5.99  5.41  4.83  4.41
D  5.06  4.64  4.08  3.65
E  5.09  4.50  3.62  3.62
```

And then [`to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
df.to_excel(`file.xlsx`)
```

Comment: Ok fine. But I need to export into excel !